# Emoji integration in angular in textarea input fields i am using reactive form

Tags: angular, typescript, emoji, picker, angular14

I am using

```
npm i @ctrl/ngx-emoji-mart
```

not able to do
using "@angular/core": "^14.2.8",
after importing module getting this error
The component 'PickerComponent' appears in 'imports', but is not standalone and cannot be imported directly. It must be imported via an NgModule.

I am expecting in textarea emoji option